# weblogic as ssl client (single side auth)

Tags: ssl, client, weblogic

How can i make weblogic to work as client in ssl authentication.

Comment: Note that client-side authentication is often referred to as two-way SSL/TLS authentication (as you'd want to authenticate the server anyway), not "single side" as in your title.

Answer (score 2):

There is [an example on the Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/security/SSL_client.html#wp1033777)

> You can use a URL object to make an
>   outbound SSL connection from a
>   WebLogic Server instance acting as a
>   client to another WebLogic Server
>   instance. The
>   weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection 
>   class provides a way to specify the
>   security context information for a
>   client, including the digital
>   certificate and private key of the
>   client.
>
> The
>   weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection
>   class provides methods for determining
>   the negotiated cipher suite,
>   getting/setting a hostname verifier,
>   getting the server’s certificate
>   chain, and getting/setting an
>   SSLSocketFactory in order to create
>   new SSL sockets.